# If $abc=25,$ find maximum $M=\frac{1}{b+c+12a}+\frac{1}{c+a+12b}+\frac{1}{a+b+12c}.$

Tags: inequality, symmetric-polynomials, uvw

> **Problem.** Let  $a,b,c>0:abc=25.$ Find maximum $$M=\frac{1}{b+c+12a}+\frac{1}{c+a+12b}+\frac{1}{a+b+12c}.$$

---

I've tried [a new method $uvw$](https://brilliant.org/wiki/the-uvw-method/)

When I set $a=b=5;c=1,$ calculate and I get $M=\dfrac{5}{66}.$ We will prove $$\frac{1}{b+c+12a}+\frac{1}{c+a+12b}+\frac{1}{a+b+12c}\le \dfrac{5}{66}.$$
After full expanding, it remains to prove $f(u,v)\ge 0,$ where $a+b+c=3u; ab+bc+ca=3v^2; abc=w^3; u\ge v\ge 1.$

The task is consider fixed sign of $f'(u), f'(v)$ and we prove the inequality is true when two of equal variables.

I have just learnt about $uvw$ recently so I gave brief idea.

Am I in right approach? Please help me find troubles if my idea is wrong.

By the way, I also hope to see others proof. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $a=b=5$ and $c=1$ we obtain a value $\frac{5}{66}.$

We'll prove that it's a maximal value.

Indeed, let $a+b+c=3u$, $ab+ac+bc=3v^2$ and $abc=w^3$.

Thus, $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{a+b+12c}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{3u+11c}=\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}(3u+11c)(3u+11b)}{\prod\limits_{cyc}(3u+11a)}=$$
$$=\frac{225u^2+363v^2}{324u^3+1089uv^2+1331w^3}$$ and we need to prove that
$$\frac{225u^2+363v^2}{324u^3+1089uv^2+1331w^3}\leq \frac{5}{66}$$ or $f(v^2)\geq0,$ where $f$ is a linear function.

But the linear function gets a minimal value for an extremal value of $v^2$, which by $uvw$ happens for equality case of two variables.

Let $b=a$ and $c=\frac{25}{a^2}.$

Thus, it's enough to prove that:
$$\frac{2}{13a+\frac{25}{a^2}}+\frac{1}{2a+\frac{300}{a^2}}\leq\frac{5}{66},$$ which gives $$(a-5)^2(64a^4+89a^3-735a^2+300a+750)\geq0,$$ which is true because by AM-GM:
$$64a^4+89a^3-735a^2+300a+750\geq\left(2\sqrt{64\cdot750}+2\sqrt{89\cdot300}-735\right)a^2>$$
$$>\left(2\sqrt{64\cdot729}+2\sqrt{81\cdot289}-735\right)a^2=3a^2>0.$$

Comment: (+1). Is there a typo in your proof ? "But the linear function gets a MINIMAL value...."

Comment: @TATA box Yes, we need to prove that $f(v^2)\geq0$ and $0$ is a minimum value of $f$.

Comment: Oh yes, now I get it. Thank you again.

Answer (score -2):

Calculus approach (Method of Lagrange's multiplier).

Let $M(a,b,c)=\frac{1}{A}+\frac{1}{B}+\frac{1}{C}$ where $A=b+c+12a$, $B=a+c+12b$, $C=a+b+12c$ and let $g(a,b,c)=abc-25$. We Eliminating $\lambda$ in the system $\frac{\partial M}{\partial i}=\lambda\frac{\partial g}{\partial i}$, $i=a,b,c$. We obtain the cyclic system
$$cyc: (13bc-ab-cA)A^2=(13ac-ab-bc)B^2$$
and by using $B^2-A^2=(B-A)(B+A)$, we have the system
$$cyc:\\ 11(b-a)(2b+13c+13a)(13ac-ab-bc)=14c(b-a)A^2$$
Hence, $b=a$ leads to extrema. But, I still couldn't prove that all is such.

And $b=a$ leads to the equation
$$221a^9-34650a^6+915625a^3-4687500=0$$
which has three positive real roots. The largest $a=5$ gives the maximum of the function.

Comment: I have a question. Can the symmetry principle apply for the following function (symmetric in $a, b$)? $$f(a, b) := {\frac {500ab \left( a+b \right) ^{2}}{ \left(  \left( a+b \right) ^
{2}+36\,{b}^{2} \right)  \left(  \left( a+b \right) ^{2}+36\,{a}^{2}
 \right) }}.
$$ (*Note*: Subject to $a, b > 0$, the maximum of $f$ is $\frac{125}{648}(1 + \sqrt{37})$ when $a = 1, b = 0.274429...$.)

Comment: @Bob Dobbs More example. Maximum of $\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2-ab+b^2)=12$, where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are non-negatives such that $a+b+c=3$. Where does the equality occur?

Comment: They are specific examples. Many thanks.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg, I think it should be maximum $\prod_{cyc}(a^2-ab+b^2)$ is $12$ at $(0,1,2).$ Am I miss something?

Comment: @TATA box Yes, of course. It says that the Bob Dobbs's reasoning is wrong.

Comment: Of course more rigorous way is to take partial derivatives of $f(a,b)$ and go on. But, ı dont have time to do that. I still think that downvoting is pushing the calculus method out. I can delete my answer if OP downvoted.

Comment: @TATAbox $a=0$ is boundary.

Comment: @RiverLi Your example is one piece.

Comment: @BobDobbs By the way, I did not downvote you.

Comment: I know my solution does not deserve upvoting it is too long for a comment answer anyway. But İ feel like downvoting is kinda teasing. Anyway, I am trying to fill the gap. Looking at Lagrange multipliers right now.  Complicated.

Comment: @BobDobbs If you take derivatives and find all stationary points, it is perhaps not easy to verify by hand. In other words, I would like to see a human verifiable proof. In contrast, someone likes to put it in Mathematica with output "True" (I think this is not a human verifiable proof).

Comment: @BobDobbs Can you give details of eliminating λ
 in the system to obtain the cyclic system? You only write the rough outline which is not enough for a complete solution, I think. In other words, without the details, it is equivalent to saying "by the method of Lagrange Multiplier, we have $(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)=0$". (Say again, I did not downvote you although I criticize your answer.)

Comment: I made a mistake when eliminating $\lambda$. ::(

Comment: You may use @ because I did not get notification. Did you correct the mistake?

Comment: I will ask this as a seperate question maybe a clever student solves the system for symmetry principle. @ri