# Minimize $\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{a+b+1}{c+ab}}$ if $ab+bc+ca=1.$

Tags: inequality, examples-counterexamples, holder-inequality

> **Problem.** Let $a,b,c$ be non-negative real numbers satisfying $ab+bc+ca=1.$ Find the minimal value $$P= \sqrt{\frac{a+b+1}{c+ab}}+\sqrt{\frac{c+b+1}{a+cb}}+\sqrt{\frac{a+c+1}{b+ac}}.$$

I saw the problem was posted [here.](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6t243f6h3128031_minimum_abbcca1)

By $a=b=1;c=0$ I got that $P\ge \sqrt{3}+2\sqrt{2}$ and tried to prove it is desired minimum.

My idea is using Holder inequality$$\left(\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{a+b+1}{c+ab}}\right)^2.\sum_{cyc}(c+ab)(a+b+1)^2[(\sqrt{6}-1)c+a+b]^3\ge \left[\sum_{cyc}(a+b+1)[(\sqrt{6}-1)c+a+b]\right]^3.$$
Hence, it is enough to prove
\begin{align*}
\left[\sum_{cyc}(a+b+1)[(\sqrt{6}-1)c+a+b]\right]^3&\ge (11+4\sqrt{6})\sum_{cyc}(c+ab)(a+b+1)^2[(\sqrt{6}-1)c+a+b]^3,
\end{align*}
which seems ugly but it is true by checking $b=a; c=\dfrac{1-a^2}{2a}.$

I am not sure that $uvw$ help to prove that last one.

About $uvw,$ see [here.](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h278791)

> I'd like to ask two question.

1. **Is $\sqrt{3}+2\sqrt{2}$ good minimum enough ?**

The reason is almost symmetrical inequalities achieve extremal value at two equal variables but this statement isn't true in some cases.

In [Bob Dobbs's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4746994/if-abc-25-find-maximum-m-frac1bc12a-frac1ca12b-frac1ab12), River Li and Michael Rozenberg gave two examples which made me confusing to think of the symmetry principle application.

If you find similar problem, please free to leave it at comment part.

2. **In case my answer is correct:**

Is there others simpler using Holder for the OP?

Also, if you find something interesting to prove the inequality, please share it here.

All idea and comment is welcome. Thank you for interest!

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg Is there something wrong ? I got your answer but it is no longer viewable

Comment: Sometimes it happens. The inequality is true for equality case of two variables, but is wrong in the general.

Comment: There is a very nice proof which uvw is dominated

Comment: @Dragon boy Show it. But read please before my post with counterexample.

Comment: @Dragonboy You're welcome to share us your proof.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Of course. I think the problem is easy by uvw but I will show simple and better proof for later. Keep waiting!

Comment: Now I see that we can use Jichen lemma and it suffices to prove three inequality

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Did you try Holder ? I found that my newest Holder  also leads to wrong thing

Comment: @TATA box I tried, but without success

Comment: Where is better proof, @Dragonboy ?

Comment: It is$\sqrt{\frac{a+b+1}{kc+ab}}+\sqrt{\frac{c+b+1}{ka+cb}}+\sqrt{\frac{a+c+1}{kb+ac}}\ge \sqrt{3}+2\sqrt{\frac{2}{k}}, k_1\le k\le k_2$ where $k_1=0.768, k_2\approx1.3945,$  of course

Comment: @Dragonboy Do you have proof for that statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Some thoughts**.

*Remarks*: Dragon boy's answer using Ji Chen's lemma is nice.
Holder also works.

I got the same form of Holder inequality independently.
Actually, I used the same idea to obtain the form of Holder inequality [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4743736/prove-sum-limits-mathrmcyc-sqrt5a5b8ab-ge-3-sqrt22-sqrt5-for/4769918#4769918).

We use the pqr method.

Let $p = a + b + c, q = ab + bc + ca = 1, r = abc$.

The desired inequality is written as
\begin{align*}
  &\left( 80\,p\sqrt {6}+66\,\sqrt {6}-230\,p-156 \right) {r}^{2}\\
  &\qquad +
 \left( 2\,{p}^{4}\sqrt {6}-6\,{p}^{3}\sqrt {6}+43\,{p}^{4}+67\,{p}^{2
 }\sqrt {6}+21\,{p}^{3}-64\,p\sqrt {6}\right.\\
&\qquad\qquad \left. -22\,{p}^{2}-220\,\sqrt {6}+124\,
 p+520 \right) r\\
 &\qquad +8\,{p}^{5}\sqrt {6}+8\,{p}^{6}+{p}^{4}\sqrt {6}+{p}^{5
 }-73\,{p}^{3}\sqrt {6}-46\,{p}^{4}-36\,{p}^{2}\sqrt {6}\\
&\qquad\qquad +68\,{p}^{3}+
 156\,p\sqrt {6}+156\,{p}^{2}+144\,\sqrt {6}-312\,p-352\\
 &\ge 0.
\end{align*}
It is quadratic in $r$. So it is tractable.

Answer (score 0):

The inequality, which you got is wrong.

For $c=0$ the condition gives $ab=1$ and we need to prove that:
$$(2(\sqrt6)-1)+(\sqrt6+2)(a+b))^3\geq$$
$$\geq (11+4\sqrt6)((a+b+1)^2(a+b)^3+a(b+1)^2((\sqrt6-1)a+b)^3+b(a+1)^2((\sqrt6-1)b+a)^3),$$ which is wrong for $a\rightarrow+\infty$.

Comment: Ok, now the answer is viewable. Thank you! I'll check it carefully

Comment: Yes, you are right @Michael Rozenberg. My Holder using is not appropriate.

Comment: @TATAbox you made a serious mistake when check the estimate

Comment: @Dragonboy Yes, a valuable lesson.

Answer (score 0):

**A sketch of proof**

Apply [Jichen's lemma](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h194103) for $$x=\dfrac{a+b+1}{c+ab};y=\dfrac{c+b+1}{a+cb};z=\dfrac{a+c+1}{b+ac};u=3; v=w=2, p=\frac{1}{2}$$
it suffices to prove

- $x+y+z\ge u+v+w=7$
- $xy+yz+zx\ge uv+vw+wu=16$
- $xyz\ge uvw=12$

We can easily prove above inequalities true by $uvw$ technique.

*Notice* All of them can be written as $$f(w^3)=kw^6+A(u,v^2)w^3+B(u,v^2)\ge 0,$$where $k<0.$

The rest is proving in two cases which is just calculus working.

Comment: I checked your statements. It is true and you should complete it  instead of giving just key

Comment: @TATAbox I wrote it compactly enough. You should full it by $uvw$